# How to find recordset with highest field value using MAX function where field is a string?

Tags: sql, vba

I have a table in Microsoft Access with multiple repeated records, containing different values in a specific column field. Due to original design, the column field type is a Short Text, whose values contains all numbers, except a "No Number" selection, and cannot be changed for the time being.

In VBA, I'm trying to find the record containing the highest value in Field3. For example, the table might look like this:

```
Field1 | Field2 | Field3
Jay        Red      2
Aden       Blue     1
Jay        Red      5
Colin      Orange   3
Jay        Red    No Number
```

I would like to return the recordset containing the row containing **Jay, Red, 5**.

I wrote an SQL string, but do to my limited knowledge, it's not right because Access complains about the following:

[image]

Here's what the SQL string looks:

```
mySQL = "SELECT " & _
            "(SELECT TOP 1 Field3" & _
             "FROM MyTable" & _
             "Where Field1 = '" & rs1.Fields("Field1") & "'" & _
             ") as Field3, Field1, Field2 " & _
             "FROM " & _
             "(SELECT Max(Val(Field3)) As Fld3, Field1, Field2 " & _
             "FROM MyTable" & _
             "GROUP BY Field3, Field1, Field2)"
                        
            criteria = "Field1= '" & rs1.Fields("Field1") & "'"

Set rs2 = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(mySQL, _
                                 dbOpenSnapshot, _
                                 dbReadOnly)

With rs2
    rs2.FindLast criteria 
                
    If Not rs2.NoMatch Then
        Dim str1 As String
                    
        str1 = rs2.Fields("Field3")

        rs2.Close
        Set rs2 = Nothing        
End With
```

I dont think the SQL string is right in general, but I'm also not sure how to use the MAX function in the cause where the column field is a string? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this quite simply with an SQL that looks like this:

```
SELECT TOP 1 Field1, Field2, Field3
FROM MyTable
WHERE Field3 <> 'No Number'
ORDER BY CInt(Field3) DESC;
```

This assumes that the only non-numeric value is 'No Number'.

Combining TOP 1 with ORDER BY DESC has the same effect of getting the maximum value, but is simpler, because there is no need for a sub-select.  If you need to add other criteria, just 'AND' them to the WHERE clause.

EDIT

Following your comment, that you might need to include 'No Number', change the SQL to:

```
SELECT TOP 1 Field1, Field2, Field3
FROM MyTable
WHERE -- your criteria here
ORDER BY CInt(IIF(Field3='No Number',0,Field3)) DESC;
```

I am assuming here that Field3 is always a number higher than 1 when it exists.  If it can be 0, then set the default in the IIF to a negative number.

Comment: thanks, but I need the recordset to be found based on the `WHERE` condition of `Field1` in the first `rs1` recordset, not the condition of `Field3`. Does it change the logic of your code? UPDATE: didn't see your bottom description. I'll check on my end. Thanks!

Comment: Works great, but one remaining question. I added another criteria in the WHERE clause to  look for a record in `rs2` based on the field value of `rs1`. How can I still store the found record in `rs2` if it only contains 'No Number' as the value of `Field3`?

Comment: Please see my edit

Comment: I just thought of an edge case, and was wondering, since `Field3` is a `Short Text` type, i.e. a `String`, I want to change the argument inside `IIF` to be `IIF(Field3='No Number','No Number',Field3)`, so if `Field3='No Number'`, then set it as `No Number` instead of 0, otherwise set it to `Field3`. However, I'm getting a `Data type mismatch in criteria expression` due to the conversion of a `String` to an `Int` from the `CInt` function. I removed `CInt`, but if the value of `Field3` > 10, the `SELECT` does not grab that record and grabs anything below `Field3 = 10`. How can I achieve this?

Comment: You should leave the IIF as I have given it.  The reason being that we want to include it in the order by, and for this we need to convert it into an integer.  Your version makes no change at all - it is the same as just Field!

Comment: If you still hae a problem, please open  new question describing your edge case exactly.  Sample data and expected result would make life easier